# Schema markup for page view trigger not fired in GTM

Tags: html, json, google-tag-manager, database-schema

I am new to structured data and to Google Tag Manager. I have created some schema markups and checked them in the Google schema markup testing tool and there both the code as well as the url for the schema markups I made were correct and detected.

But in the GTM it appears that the schema markups are not fired. I read somewhere that one cause could be that the order of the code and the GTM link are not as supposed to be. So I have added two screenshot of GTM and one of the code of the website where the markup is implemented below.

How could I solve this and make it fire?

[Screenshot tags not fired in GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmMnj.png)

[GTM not fired tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKHCR.png)

[Princscreen of the code: link to GTM, script with the function and ld+jsaon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCOtN.png)

[screenshot of the trigger configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ida8C.png)

I have made a custom event as a trigger but that did also not fire.